# Отладчик отображает для всех вызовов рекурсии setTimeout один и тот же scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль, рекурсия, settimeout

**1.** Обычная рекурсия.

[image: stack1]
[image: stack2]

```js
function pow(x, n) {
  if (n != 1) {
    return x * pow(x, n - 1);
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}

console.log( pow(2, 3) );
```

**2.** Рекурсия с использование метода `setTimeout`.

[image: stack3]
[image: stack4]

```js
var timerId = setTimeout(function tick(a) {
  if ( 0 < a ) {
    console.log( "тик" );
    timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}, 2000, 5);

console.log(window);
```

На втором изображении выделилась 4 строка, ибо я попробовал выбрать определенный вызов в `stack`, но меня не переместило в него, и все так же показывает последнее контекст. Еще я обратил внимание что в `Call Stack` указано `setTimeout(async)`.

**3.** Попробовал реализовать рекурсию как в первом примере с использованием `setTimeout`.

```js
setTimeout(function tick(a) {
  if (0 < a) {
    console.log("тик");
    return 2 * setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1);
  } else {
    return 123;
  }
}, 2000, 2);

console.log(window);
```

Я хотел сделать глубокую рекурсию через `setTimeout`, и посмотреть будет ли выход из нее, но этого не произошло.

**Итог:**

**1.** С первым примером все ясно.

**2.** Здесь мне не понятно зачем нужны стеки, если их нельзя просмотреть.

**3.** В этом примере хотел сделать рекурсию через `setTimeout` частью выражения, что бы потом вернуть значение через стек, но этого не произошло, так как `сборщик мусора` все зачистил. Я предполагаю, что как только таймер перестает быть актуальным, то `сборщик мусора` сразу ее чистит, но мне все равно не понятно почему он игнорирует тот факт, что вызов был в контексте выражения `return 2 * setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1);`, и оно по идеи ждем результата как в первом пункте. Вот более наглядный пример в [статье](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion#%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-pow-x-n-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E).

P.S: В третьем пункте итогов было заблуждение, и в следствии он полностью ошибочный:

> **3.** В этом примере хотел сделать рекурсию через `setTimeout` частью выражения, что бы потом вернуть значение через стек, но этого не произошло, так как `сборщик мусора` все зачистил. Я предполагаю, что как только таймер перестает быть актуальным, то `сборщик мусора` сразу ее чистит, но мне все равно не понятно почему он игнорирует тот факт, что вызов был в контексте выражения `return 2 * setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1);`, и оно по идеи ждем результата как в первом пункте. Вот более наглядный пример в [статье](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion#%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-pow-x-n-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E).

`return 2 * setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1);` возвращает `id - числовой идентификатор таймера`, но по мима получения `id` опять происходит вызов.

Comment: "вызов был в контексте выражения return 2 * setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1);" - это что значит? В случаях с `setTimeout` нет никакого стэка.

Comment: Я хотел этим сказать, что выражение ждем результата вызова `setTimeout(tick, 2000, a - 1)`, а значит стек не должен очиститься пока этот вызов не вернет что либо, но так как тут используется метод `setTimeout`, то и работает это возможно по другому, по этому и задал вопрос, что бы пояснили. На счет стека у `setTimeout`, я глаголил исходя увиденного в консоли, а в ней он есть.

Comment: @Igor Может тут и нет как таковой рекурсии в том смысле, что функция не сама себя вызывает, а это делает метод `setTimeout`.

Comment: Какой смысл команды `return` внутри функции, поданной в `setTimeout`? Куда она что-то возвращает? Никакого результата `setTimeout` не ждет. Обдумайте понятие "асинхронность", помедитируйте.

Comment: @Igor вы обратили внимание, что мы находимся на площадке где люди задают вопросы? Я думаю мне не надо продолжать свою мысль. Можно по конкретней на счет асинхронности. По поводу смысла, то что бы что - то понять, надо поэкспериментировать и разобраться. Не просто так люди проводят опыты.